# calling method outside class python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm relatively new to Python and OOP, I'm trying to write a mini adventure game with classes and have gotten stuck with my BattleEngine class.
The idea is to have options to fight or outwit an opponent based on your characters and the opponents 'strength' and 'wit'.
I get an error when I try to call my attack method here:

```
class Armory(Scene):

    def enter(self):
        print "This room appears to be some kind of armory. There are shelves full of weaponry lining"
        print "the walls. You walk around admiring the shiny weapons, you reach out to pick up a"
        print "massive battleaxe. Right as your fingers touch it you hear voices from behind the"
        print "next door. They sound like they're getting closer. As the voices grow nearer you must make"
        print "a decision. Will you stand and fight (enter 'fight') or will you use your wit to outsmart"
        print "your opponent(enter 'wit')?"
        decision = raw_input("> ")
        battle = BattleEngine()
        if decision == "fight":
            attack(self, Player.strength, 3)
            if player_wins:
                print "A man in light armour walks in and sees you with your sword drawn. A look of"
                print "shock and disbelief is on his face. You act quickly and lunge at him."
                print "The soldier struggles to unsheath his sword as you run him through."
                print "He collapses to the ground wearing the same look of disbelief."
                print "Your strength has increased by 1."
                Player.strength += 1
        elif decision == "wit":
            outwit(self, Player.wit, 3)
```

Here is where I defined my BattleEngine class:

```
class BattleEngine(object):

    def attack(self, player_strength, nonplayer_strength):
        player_roll = randint(1,6)
        nonplayer_roll = randint(1,6)
        if (player_roll + player_strength) >= (nonplayer_roll + nonplayer_strength):
            return player_wins
        else: 
            return 'death'

    def outwit(self, player_wit, nonplayer_wit):
        player_roll = randint(1,6)
        nonplayer_roll = randint(1,6)
        if (player_roll + player_wit) >= (nonplayer_roll + nonplayer_wit):
            return player_wins
        else: 
            return 'death'
```

Once I get to this point in my program is receive the error that : 'attack global name is not defined'
I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong exactly. Any help would be fantastic!

Comment: After you fix this… your `player_wins` isn't handled right. I think inside `enter` you want to set `player_wins` to the result of calling `attack`, and then check it; and in `attack`, you want to return `True` instead of some global variable named `player_wins` if the player wins, and `False` instead of `'death'` otherwise.

Comment: Also, you almost definitely want `strength` and `wit` to be instance attributes of the `Player` class, not class attributes. If there are multiple players, they each have different `strength` values, right? For example, if I finish the game and restart as a new character, I won't have the same strength as last time.

Comment: The way I've arranged the code is that the `strength` and `wit` attributes reset if the user chooses to play a new game.

Comment: That's not the right way to do it. The whole point of OOP is that each `Player` instance represents a player, while the `Player` class represents the whole class of all possible players. Class attributes are only used for values that should be shared by all players.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call `attack` *on* your `BattleEngine` instance, and you do *not* need to pass in `self`:

```
battle = BattleEngine()
if decision == "fight":
    player_wins = battle.attack(Player.strength, 3)
```

Note that you need to receive the return value of the `.attack()` method.

The same applies to the `.outwit()` method further on:

```
elif decision == "wit":
    player_wins = battle.outwit(Player.wit, 3)
```

You probably need to fix the return values in the `.attack()` and `.outwit()` methods; instead of `return player_wins` and `return 'death'`, return `True` or `False` perhaps.

The `self` parameter is taken care of for you by Python, and will refer to the specific `BattleEngine` instance.

Not that you really *need* classes here, your `BattleEngine()` class currently has no per-instance state, for example. You don't use `self` in any of the methods, because there is nothing on the instance to refer *to*.

Comment: Great! I fixed both things and it all works as I planned it. By not needing classes you mean I could just define the functions attack and outwit somewhere else correct?

Comment: Indeed; classes without state only serve as glorified namespaces.